# Getting different pixel depths from output raster when done in ArcMap versus Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, pixel, bit-depth

When I use 'Plus' in Spatial Analyst to add together two 8-bit unsigned rasters (pixel values 0-100) the output raster is 8-bit unsigned (pixel values 0-200) but when I try and do the same thing running a python script the output is a 32 signed raster (pixel values 0-200) . How can I adjust my code to have the output be an 8-bit raster?

```
# Import needed modules
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
raster1 = arcpy.Raster("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Raster_test\Confidence_2008_56m.tif")
raster2 = arcpy.Raster("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Raster_test\Producers_2008_56m.tif")
# Execute Plus
outPlus = Plus(raster1, raster2)
# Save the output 
outPlus.save("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Raster_test\script_plus2.tif")
```

Comment: Although I can't confirm this is the case for this tool, please see this answer to [How to reduce Polygon to Raster (Conversion) bit depth?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104110/64785) which suggests that there is no way to control bit-depth in some ArcGIS tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven'y found a direct answer to my question online but reading about similar issues your suggestion may be the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you did your analysis you can Copy your output with `arcpy.CopyRaster_management`. Where you can specify bit depth through the pixel_type arg. For example - `arcpy.CopyRaster_management("inrast","outrast","","","-9999", "","","8_BIT")`

You can then delete the earlier output to cleanup.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, worked like a charm! I replaced the Output.save() with the arcpy.CopyRaster_management()

Comment: great!, if this worked please tick the "accepted answer" green tick, so other users can see the question as an accepted answer. Cheers